# Unable to setVisible(false) of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, inner-classes, final

I am creating a Medical Shop Billing software in which I have three `JFrames` one of which I need to `setVisible(false)` on the click a `JMenuItem`. However each time I compile an error is displayed

```
JFrame f is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You need to post your code for us to give you better advice

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Basically `JFrame f..` needs to be `final JFrame f..`.  Better advice will come with an SSCCE from you.

Answer (score 1):

Inner local class object is created in the context of the outer class object, if you refer a outer class Object to your inner class What happens when a method terminates and the value changes during execution of the method? Those local variables should be kept in existence although they are local variables.

Solution is that you have to make those local variable `final`. It is an indication to the compiler that that `variable` should be copied to somewhere else (if required) when the `method` itself terminates.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access variable on outer class. You need to add final like this:

```
final public JFrame frame
```

You can read here for more information
[final (Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) on Wikipedia.

Comment: sorry, just started posting stackoverflow few day before.